# grant ownership to everybody / remove ownership completely

Tags: linux, macos, multi-boot, ntfs, ownership

I had a dual boot system with Win10 and Mint 19.3 for some time and I am now in the process of adding a hackintosh to the mix.

I have a NTFS partition to which all three should have access. Between Win and Mint, I never had problems with that, but macOS is complaining about ownership issuess.

How can I remove the ownership restrictions from that partition, so that either macOS can own it or everybody owns it at the same time? And in what way would I compromise the security of my data in doing so, for example when treating with my thunderbird-profile?

Comment: NTFS is not be the best format to use with MacOS. You will have better luck with FAT32.

Comment: Yes, but that has the restriction of 4gb files. I've set up ntfs-3g, so read and write works, but using the files sometimes is not possible.

Comment: Then use [exFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT).